# How to set the content type on the servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I am using a simple servlet which sends back document contents from the database as a byte array. I would like to set a content [type](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentType(java.lang.String)) so that it has an appropriate extension while it is being retrieved via a doGet() call.

I do have the type of the document stored as a metadata in the database (e.g. png, gif, png, xls, docx ...).

1. What should I set as the content type so that it retains the file extension?
2. The file gets downloaded with a name of "doc", how do I set the filename on the servlet for the data being downloaded.

Comment: possible duplicate of [make document available for download through java/servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840703/make-document-available-for-download-through-java-servlet)

Answer (score 16):

> *What should I set as the content type so that it retains the file extension?*

Use `ServletContext#getMimeType()` to get the mime type based on the file name.

```
String mimeType = getServletContext().getMimeType(filename);
```

The servletcontainer usually already provides a default mime type mapping in its own `web.xml`. If you want to overridde or add some other, then put it as new mime mappings in webapp's `web.xml`. E.g.

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>docx</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>xlsx</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Finally set it as the `Content-Type` response header:

```
response.setContentType(mimeType);
```

---

> *The file gets downloaded with a name of "doc", how do I set the filename on the servlet for the data being downloaded.*

Add it to the servlet URL because some browsers like MSIE ignores the `filename` attribute of the content disposition.

```
<a href="download/filename.ext">download filename.ext</a>
```

If the servlet is mapped on an URL pattern of `/download/*`, then you can obtain it as follows

```
String filename = request.getPathInfo().substring(1);
```

Finally set it in the `Content-Disposition` header as well to make normal browsers happy:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
```

If you don't store filenames in DB but rather IDs or something, then use it as filename instead.

```
<a href="download/${file.id}.${file.ext}">download ${file.id}.${file.ext}</a>
```

And then in the servlet

```
String filename = request.getPathInfo().substring(1);
String id = filename.split("\\.")[0];
// Obtain from DB based on id.
```

Answer (score 8):

> 1. What should I set as the content type so that it retains the file
>      extension?

You can use the setContentType method of response object to set the mime. eg:

```
response.setContentType("your-correct-mime-here");
```

> 2.The file gets downloaded with a name of "doc", how do I set the
>   filename on the servlet for the data
>   being downloaded

You can set the filename of the file being downloaded by setting the correct header. You can use Content-Disposition as shown below:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + your_file_name + "\"");
```

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840703/make-document-available-for-download-through-java-servlet/1840925#1840925

Comment: Note "your-filename" has a few problems. 1) Not a valid variable name. 2) Quotes are useful: `filename=\"" + filename + "\""`.

Comment: @Dave, thanks for pointing out the mistakes. "your-filename" was not a variable... i was making it easy for the person to read and made a mistake by over simplified it!