# Model Object in GWT with Blob as an Attribute

Tags: mysql, gwt, download, blob

I have a GWT application based on the MVP+App Controller Design. I also have a MySQL database as the back-end persistence storage.

In my **shared** folder I have a **Feed ** model object. Feed objects are to be fetched as an ArrayList by my application(Imagining it to be a twitter like Application)

Each Feed Model object in my Application can have an attached document with it. However it is optional. If the user requests for the attachment by clicking I would want to server the Attached document.

I had in mind of keeping a Blob refrence as one of the Attribute of my Feed object. However GWT does not allow using Blob class for Client side code.(**shared** folder is used by client as well as server side code)
Getting the attached documents for all the Feeds and passing around a byte of Array will take a lot of bandwidth. :|

What can be a possible way around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a Blob on client side. And as you said you don't want to pass such large data in your model object anyway.

What you want to do is only have a reference to a uniqueId for the Blob in your Feed object. When the user tries to access the document, send an http request with that id as a parameter to a Servlet on your server side. This servlet will use the id to get the Blob from the database and return the file as an attachment (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840703) for example to set headers)